# How can I insert custom dialog before WelcomeDlg?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, package

I want to let the user select the language before start the welcome dialog in WiX, so that the installer can install the different features for each language.

So far, I have created my own custom dialog that contains ComboBox, I am aware of how to insert custom dialog between any other dialog, but I have no idea how to insert it before the WelcomeDlg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not done it but I am sure it can be easily done:

At the bottom of the WelcomeDlg you should see this:

```
  <InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="WelcomeDlg" After="CostFinalize" Overridable="yes">NOT Installed OR PATCH</Show>
  </InstallUISequence>
```

This allows you to override the dialog sequence. Schedule your custom dialog to run after `CostFinalize` and before WelcomeDlg. I haven't tested this but it should easily be done.

```
  <InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="CustomDlg" After="CostFinalize">NOT Installed OR PATCH</Show>
    <Show Dialog="CustomDlg" Before="WelcomeDlg">NOT Installed OR PATCH</Show>
  </InstallUISequence>
```

Comment: When I try following your advice by putting the code in my custom UI page, I got following errors.
`E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\WixUI_Advanced.wxs(35) :
 error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:ApplicationFolderName
' in section 'Fragment:'.
E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\InstallScopeDlg.wxs(20)
: error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:WixAppFolder' in sec
tion 'Fragment:'.`

It seems there is a problem when I try to use `Before` or `After` with only a dialog

Comment: Actually, I found that only the first command,

`<Show Dialog="CustomDlg" After="CostFinalize">NOT Installed OR PATCH</Show>` is enough.

Thank you !

Comment: My bad, only the first line mess the sequence up, If I use only first line, the sequence would be like `CustomDlg > WelcomeDlg > VerifyDlg > WelcomDlg > VerifyDlg > InstallDlg > ExitDlg` let's say if I press the Install button it will popup the `WelcomeDlg` again. Could you help me out ?

Comment: Create your own welcome dialog - just take the code from the WIX dialog and take out the `<InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="WelcomeDlg" After="CostFinalize" Overridable="yes">NOT Installed OR PATCH</Show>
  </InstallUISequence> ` at the end and then hook up your back and Next buttons to the correct dialogs should sort you out.

Comment: It seems that I have a problem when trying to run
`<Show Dialog="MyCustomDlg" Before="WelcomeDlg" >NOT Installed OR PATCH</Show>` it said that `error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol WixAction:InstallUISequence/WelcomeDlg' in section 'Fragment:'.`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Sequence attribute:

```
<InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="SplashDlg" Sequence="1" >NOT Installed OR PATCH</Show>
</InstallUISequence>
```